# javascript to create multiple checkboxes in for statement

Tags: javascript, checkbox, for-loop

Hi I am trying to create a bunch of checkboxes without having to make each one currently I have:

```
function test(obj) {
    if (document.getElementByID("info").checked == true) { 
        document.getElementById("gender")[0].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

and it works for one checkbox but I have been trying to use the code below:

```
function test(obj) {
    var x = obj.name;
    var rowCount = $('#List tr').length;
    for (var i = 0; i rowCount-1; i++) { 
        if (x == document.getElementByID("info"["+i+"]).checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("gender"["+i+"]).disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

to create as many checkboxes as I want without me having to make each one but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: WHere are you creating checkboxes? The code looks messed up in so many ways. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your HTML, and also clarify: are you trying to "create" checkboxes like your question title and initial sentence say, or trying to "determine the checked status and take some action" for your checkboxes like the code you have supplied tries to do? Some problems with your code: (1) JavaScript is case sensitive so use `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`. (2) `getElementById("gender")[0]` isn't right because that function does not return an array. (3) The condition in your `for` loop is missing a `<`. (4) More things that won't fit in this comment.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, lets start from the beginning:

To create a check-box in javascript you must do something like this:

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
```

Then to add your checkbox into a div on your webpage you would do something like:

```
document.getElementById("your_div_id").appendChild(checkbox);
```

Then to see if the checkbox is checked you look at the "checked" property like so:

```
var isChecked = !!document.getElementById("your_checkbox").checked;
if(isChecked == true){
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

Here's a function that would loop through a bunch of checkboxes

```
function testCheckBoxes(container_id){
    var checkboxes = document.querySelector("#" + container_id + " > input[type='checkbox']");
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(!!checkboxes[i].checked == true){
            // Your code
        }
}
```

[Side Note: I'm using `document.querySelector` for consistency but since I think you're using jquery then use `$` instead]
If you want to do something when someone clicks on your checkbox the use an event listener:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        if(!!event.target.checked == true){
            // Do something
        }
    }, true);
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. Good Luck =)